# refreshing data in component after BehaviorSubject changed

Tags: angular

i have a total price in BehavoiurSubject

```
export class ShoppingCartService {
    public totalPriceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number> (this.getTotalPrice(this.loadOrderedProducts()));
    
    getTotalPrice(selectedProducts: SelectedProductOrderModel[]): number {
        let totalPrice = 0;
            for (const orderedProduct of selectedProducts) {
                totalPrice += orderedProduct.quantity * orderedProduct.product!.price;
            }
            return totalPrice;
        }
    }
```

i display it in shopping cart component.ts

```
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {
    
    totalPrice: number;
    private totalPriceSub: Subscription;
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.usersSelectedProducts = JSON.parse(<string>localStorage.getItem('selectedProductOrders'));
        this.totalPriceSub = this.cartService.totalPriceSubject
            .subscribe(totalPrice => {
                this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
            });
    }
```

.html

```
<td>${{totalPrice}}</td>
```

but when i m adding one more product in shopping cart component, totalPrice doesnt update, i need to refresh page and then i get new number. Can anyone please advise me how to solve it, i want it after i add one more product it will update totalPrice. thx

Comment: you need to call totalPriceSubject.next() while adding new order in the cart?

Comment: thank you yeah. .next() that what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do following changes in your service files

```
export class ShoppingCartService {

  calTotalPrice  = (selectedProducts: SelectedProductOrderModel[]) : number => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    for (const orderedProduct of selectedProducts) {
      totalPrice += orderedProduct.quantity * orderedProduct.product!.price;
    }
    return totalPrice;
  }
  
  public totalPriceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.calTotalPrice(cartItemList))

  totalPrice = this.totalPriceSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setTotalPrice(price: number) {
    this.totalPriceSubject.next(price);
  }

}
```

In your component, you can subscribe and receive the values.

```
this.totalPriceSub = this.cartService.totalPrice
            .subscribe(totalPrice => {
              this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
            });
```

Comment: If you want to update the price and notify the subscriber you can use setTotalPrice function. 

is it still getting undefined in your component?